# How can I monitor via jvisualvm and jstatd processes of all users?

Tags: java, unix, root, jvisualvm, jstatd

I updated to `java 1.8_66` and got following problem.
When I run locally jvisualvm I can monitor (it's meaning connect to process) only processes running under me. When I start `sudo jvisualvm`, I can monitor only root processes. And I got such problem when I monitor remote processes. Is that possible to monitor processes all of users?

Comment: On remote machine I have few users all of them have their own java processes. Running jstatd under sudo allow me connect only processes owned by sudo, and I haven't access to processes owned by another users. But before update everything works fine.